# Linking error while inheriting from a template class

Tags: c++

I have some trouble while inheriting from a class template.

```
template < typename T>
class VdpCondition : public Condition {
public:
    virtual T getElem(VehicleDataProvider) = 0;

    bool testCondition(Veins::TraCIMobility* car) {
        cModule* parent = car->getParentModule();
        assert(parent != nullptr);
        ItsG5Middleware* appl = dynamic_cast<ItsG5Middleware*>(parent->getSubmodule("appl"));
        assert(appl != nullptr);
        return (getElem(appl->getDataProvieder()) >= elem);
    }

    T elem;
};

class SpeedCondition : public VdpCondition<boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::velocity>>{
public:
    SpeedCondition(double speed)
    {
        elem = (speed * boost::units::si::meter_per_second);
    }

    boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::velocity> getElem(VehicleDataProvider prov) {
        std::cout << prov.speed().value() << std::endl;
        return prov.speed();
    }
};
```

It compiles quite well, there occur no errors, but if I try to start my application I get linking errors..

```
undefined symbol: _ZN12VdpConditionIN5boost5units8quantityINS1_4unitINS1_4listINS1_3dimINS1_21length_base_dimensionENS1_15static_rationalILl1ELl1EEEEENS4_INS5_INS1_19time_base_dimensionENS7_ILln1ELl1EEEEENS1_18dimensionless_typeEEEEENS1_18homogeneous_systemINS4_INS1_2si15meter_base_unitENS4_INS1_16scaled_base_unitINS1_3cgs14gram_base_unitENS1_5scaleILl10ENS7_ILl3ELl1EEEEEEENS4_INSH_16second_base_unitENS4_INSH_16ampere_base_unitENS4_INSH_16kelvin_base_unitENS4_INSH_14mole_base_unitENS4_INSH_17candela_base_unitENS4_INS1_5angle16radian_base_unitENS4_INSV_19steradian_base_unitESD_EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEvEEdEEEC2Ev
```

At first, I thought it was because I made getElem pure virtual and used it inside the template class, but I tried to remove all the functions of VdpCondition and the error still occurs.
Now I have no clue where I have to search for the error.

Maybe you see what I do wrong? I do not understand why this compiles but not links..

Comment: What OS are you using? From your error, this code must be in a shared library. What have you done to see if your executable is finding the shared library file?

Comment: I'm using `Ubunutu 15.04`. I'm think my executable is finding the library, because it works if I remove the instantiation of `SpeedCondition con(5)`.

Comment: @pcarter what hint do you see that implies shared library?  I see a failure at link time to find the definition of the default constructor of `VdpCondition` with template parameters as used by `SpeedCondition`.  Since the constructor of `VdpCondition` was not coded, the compiler must provide it.  Then the compiler decided not to inline it within the constructor of SpeedCondition.  But then it also didn't provide an out of line copy.  In the quoted code, I see no reason for the out of line copy to be skipped.

Comment: @Suv is the code you quoted really representative of what you actually tested?  I think you left out something that you thought didn't matter, but which fundamentally changes things.  The most simple case would be if you declared a constructor for `VdpCondition` so you must then be in control of where it is defined.  You might also get to this problem with multiple modules compiled with incompatible optimization levels.

Comment: Is it enough to provide a constructor like `VdpCondition() {}` or do I miss something? If I add this constructor, the error takes still place.. And yes, the quote is the code, like I use it in my application.

Comment: @Suv, so it's finding other code in that shared library when you run? If you set LD_DEBUG=libs and run your executable, does it show the library being found?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the library is found. There is only a problem with this `VdpCondition`.

Comment: Its magically working now.. I changed the `boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::velocity>` to an `int` than it worked.. I changed it back and its still working now... I'm confused. Thank you all!

Comment: That fits the guess of incompatible optimization settings.  Some module had been built with optimization settings incompatible with the rest of the project.  When you make a change forcing that module to be rebuilt, you bring it into compatibility with the rest of the project.